# EEPROM vs NOR Flash

Tags: memory, flash, eeprom

1. I came to know that EEPROM of these days are nothing but NOR Flash. How true is this statement? In case if it is true, why is still there a distinction between flash and EEPROM when we talk of memory types in general?
2. What is the reason for Flash being faster than EEPROM? Is it the only advantage it has over EEPROM?

Comment: I couldn't get a clear answer for at least the second question.

Comment: These days imho the main difference is that eeprom is used for small quantity of data with ease of reading and writing. Flash are much bigger and also the protocol they need is much more complicated

Comment: As for 2. Flash is cheaper. There are flash based EEPROMS where glue circutry sits around a flash memory to make it appear to the outside world as an EEPROM.

Comment: Very disappointing to see this marked as 'duplicate.' It would be more sensible to mark this as having a poor title (which it does). This is not a duplicate of the question linked. Poster is not asking what the difference between these technologies is. They are asking if the majority of EEPROMs are now simply emulated in NOR flash and why.

Comment: As the previous comment says, flash is cheaper. In the automotive industry, electronics designers generally optimize for the lowest possible per-part cost (in volume), even at the expense of more engineering effort. I can't answer the question generally whether most EEPROMs are now just emulated with flash inside, but I wouldn't be surprised. Flash is the dominant underlying technology for non-volatile RAM (NVRAM) in new automotive electronics designs (because the per-part cost is lower in volume). Low volume applications may change the value equation.